# Trying to complete R statements, getting Errors

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am working on an assignment and trying to create R statements, but keep getting errors. I have spent forever trying to figure it out. The below statements are what I have and have errors for almost all of them. These are the following directions I am trying to follow:

1. Download a dataset from the web. You may use any source, but specify the source in
   your code. Also ensure that the data has a mix of quantitative and qualitative
   (categorical) variables.
2. Import the dataset into R
3. Print out descriptive statistics for a selection of quantitative and categorical variables.
4. Transform at least one variable. It doesn't matter what the transformation is.

Below is the R statements I have been trying to do with the Errors below. I could really use any help!

```
# https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/joebeachcapital/nba-player-statistics #
# Import the dataset into R #
dataset <- read.csv("~/Downloads/nba_data_processed.csv", header=FALSE)
head(dataset)

 # Print out descriptive statistics for a selection of quantitative and categorical   variables. #
# Quantitative variables #
quant_vars <- c("Tm", "Age")
cat_vars <- c("POS", "PTS")

# Frequency table for categorical variables #
for (PTS in cat_vars) {
cat_freq <- table(dataset[PTS])
print(paste("Frequency table for", PTS))
print(cat_freq)}

Error in `[.data.frame`(dataset, PTS) : undefined columns selected

# Transform a variable #
dataset$LogAge <- log(dataset$Age)

Error in log(dataset$Age) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

# Histogram for Games Started #
dataset$GS<- as.integer(dataset$GS)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, GS, value = integer(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 706

## Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
hist(dataset$Tm, main="Tm Distribution", xlab="Tm")

Error in hist.default(dataset$Tm, main = "Tm Distribution", xlab = "Tm") : 
'x' must be numeric

# Scatterplot for Tm vs. Age #
plot(dataset$Tm, dataset$Age, main="Scatterplot: Tm vs. Age", xlab="Tm", ylab="Age")

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
>
```

I am not sure how to deal with these errors.

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(V1 = c("Player", "Precious Achiuwa", "Steven Adams", 
"Bam Adebayo", "Ochai Agbaji", "Santi Aldama", "Nickeil Alexander-Walker", 
"Nickeil Alexander-Walker", "Nickeil Alexander-Walker", "Grayson Allen", 
"Jarrett Allen", "Jose Alvarado", "Kyle Anderson", "Giannis Antetokounmpo", 
"Thanasis Antetokounmpo", "Cole Anthony", "OG Anunoby", "Ryan Arcidiacono", 
"Ryan Arcidiacono", "Ryan Arcidiacono"), V2 = c("Pos", "C", "C", 
"C", "SG", "PF", "SG", "SG", "SG", "SG", "C", "PG", "PF", "PF", 
"PF", "PG", "SF", "PG", "PG", "PG"), V3 = c("Age", "23", "29", 
"25", "22", "22", "24", "24", "24", "27", "24", "24", "29", "28", 
"30", "22", "25", "28", "28", "28"), V4 = c("Tm", "TOR", "MEM", 
"MIA", "UTA", "MEM", "TOT", "UTA", "MIN", "MIL", "CLE", "NOP", 
"MIN", "MIL", "MIL", "ORL", "TOR", "TOT", "NYK", "POR"), V5 = c("G", 
"55", "42", "75", "59", "77", "59", "36", "23", "72", "68", "61", 
"69", "63", "37", "60", "67", "20", "11", "9"), V6 = c("GS", 
"12", "42", "75", "22", "20", "3", "3", "0", "70", "68", "10", 
"46", "63", "0", "4", "67", "4", "0", "4"), V7 = c("MP", "20.7", 
"27.0", "34.6", "20.5", "21.8", "15.0", "14.7", "15.5", "27.4", 
"32.6", "21.5", "28.4", "32.1", "5.6", "25.9", "35.6", "8.6", 
"2.4", "16.2"), V8 = c("FG", "3.6", "3.7", "8.0", "2.8", "3.2", 
"2.2", "2.3", "2.1", "3.4", "5.9", "3.3", "3.7", "11.2", "0.5", 
"4.6", "6.3", "0.5", "0.1", "0.9"), V9 = c("FGA", "7.3", "6.3", 
"14.9", "6.5", "6.8", "5.0", "4.7", "5.4", "7.7", "9.2", "8.0", 
"7.2", "20.3", "1.2", "10.2", "13.2", "1.9", "0.5", "3.6"), V10 = c("FG%", 
".485", ".597", ".540", ".427", ".470", ".444", ".488", ".384", 
".440", ".644", ".411", ".509", ".553", ".435", ".454", ".476", 
".243", ".200", ".250"), V11 = c("3P", "0.5", "0.0", "0.0", "1.4", 
"1.2", "1.0", "1.0", "1.1", "2.0", "0.0", "1.4", "0.6", "0.7", 
"0.0", "1.3", "2.1", "0.4", "0.1", "0.8"), V12 = c("3PA", "2.0", 
"0.0", "0.2", "3.9", "3.5", "2.7", "2.4", "3.1", "5.1", "0.1", 
"4.0", "1.5", "2.7", "0.2", "3.4", "5.5", "1.2", "0.3", "2.2"
), V13 = c("3P%", ".269", ".000", ".083", ".355", ".353", ".384", 
".402", ".361", ".399", ".100", ".336", ".410", ".275", ".000", 
".364", ".387", ".348", ".333", ".350"), V14 = c("2P", "3.0", 
"3.7", "8.0", "1.4", "2.0", "1.2", "1.3", "1.0", "1.4", "5.9", 
"1.9", "3.0", "10.5", "0.5", "3.4", "4.2", "0.1", "0.0", "0.1"
), V15 = c("2PA", "5.4", "6.2", "14.7", "2.7", "3.4", "2.3", 
"2.3", "2.3", "2.7", "9.1", "4.0", "5.7", "17.6", "1.0", "6.7", 
"7.7", "0.7", "0.2", "1.3"), V16 = c("2P%", ".564", ".599", ".545", 
".532", ".591", ".515", ".578", ".415", ".518", ".653", ".488", 
".536", ".596", ".526", ".500", ".539", ".071", ".000", ".083"
), V17 = c("eFG%", ".521", ".597", ".541", ".532", ".560", ".547", 
".591", ".488", ".571", ".645", ".496", ".553", ".572", ".435", 
".516", ".556", ".351", ".300", ".359"), V18 = c("FT", "1.6", 
"1.1", "4.3", "0.9", "1.4", "0.7", "0.8", "0.6", "1.6", "2.4", 
"1.1", "1.4", "7.9", "0.3", "2.5", "2.1", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"
), V19 = c("FTA", "2.3", "3.1", "5.4", "1.2", "1.9", "1.0", "1.1", 
"0.9", "1.8", "3.3", "1.3", "2.0", "12.3", "0.6", "2.8", "2.5", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), V20 = c("FT%", ".702", ".364", ".806", 
".812", ".750", ".667", ".692", ".619", ".905", ".733", ".813", 
".735", ".645", ".500", ".894", ".838", "", "", ""), V21 = c("ORB", 
"1.8", "5.1", "2.5", "0.7", "1.1", "0.3", "0.2", "0.3", "0.8", 
"3.3", "0.5", "1.0", "2.2", "0.4", "0.8", "1.4", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0"), V22 = c("DRB", "4.1", "6.5", "6.7", "1.3", "3.7", "1.5", 
"1.4", "1.5", "2.4", "6.5", "1.9", "4.4", "9.6", "0.8", "4.0", 
"3.5", "0.8", "0.4", "1.2"), V23 = c("TRB", "6.0", "11.5", "9.2", 
"2.1", "4.8", "1.7", "1.6", "1.8", "3.3", "9.8", "2.3", "5.3", 
"11.8", "1.2", "4.8", "5.0", "0.8", "0.4", "1.2"), V24 = c("AST", 
"0.9", "2.3", "3.2", "1.1", "1.3", "1.8", "2.1", "1.4", "2.3", 
"1.7", "3.0", "4.9", "5.7", "0.4", "3.9", "2.0", "1.2", "0.2", 
"2.3"), V25 = c("STL", "0.6", "0.9", "1.2", "0.3", "0.6", "0.5", 
"0.7", "0.3", "0.9", "0.8", "1.1", "1.1", "0.8", "0.1", "0.6", 
"1.9", "0.3", "0.2", "0.3"), V26 = c("BLK", "0.5", "1.1", "0.8", 
"0.3", "0.6", "0.4", "0.4", "0.3", "0.2", "1.2", "0.2", "0.9", 
"0.8", "0.1", "0.5", "0.7", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), V27 = c("TOV", 
"1.1", "1.9", "2.5", "0.7", "0.8", "0.9", "1.3", "0.4", "1.0", 
"1.4", "1.3", "1.5", "3.9", "0.3", "1.5", "2.0", "0.4", "0.1", 
"0.7"), V28 = c("PF", "1.9", "2.3", "2.8", "1.7", "1.9", "1.5", 
"1.6", "1.3", "1.6", "2.3", "2.0", "2.1", "3.1", "0.6", "2.6", 
"3.0", "0.9", "0.3", "1.6"), V29 = c("PTS", "9.2", "8.6", "20.4", 
"7.9", "9.0", "6.2", "6.3", "5.9", "10.4", "14.3", "9.0", "9.4", 
"31.1", "1.4", "13.0", "16.8", "1.3", "0.3", "2.6")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The columns are:

```
Player: string - name of the player
Pos (Position): string - position played by the player
Age: integer - age of the player as of February 1, 2023
Tm (Team): string - team the player belongs to
G (Games Played): integer - number of games played by the player
GS (Games Started): integer - number of games started by the player
MP (Minutes Played): integer - total minutes played by the player
FG (Field Goals): integer - number of field goals made by the player
FGA (Field Goal Attempts): integer - number of field goal attempts by the player
FG% (Field Goal Percentage): float - percentage of field goals made by the player
3P (3-Point Field Goals): integer - number of 3-point field goals made by the player
3PA (3-Point Field Goal Attempts): integer - number of 3-point field goal attempts by the player
3P% (3-Point Field Goal Percentage): float - percentage of 3-point field goals made by the player
2P (2-Point Field Goals): integer - number of 2-point field goals made by the player
2PA (2-point Field Goal Attempts): integer - number of 2-point field goal attempts by the player
2P% (2-Point Field Goal Percentage): float - percentage of 2-point field goals made by the player
eFG% (Effective Field Goal Percentage): float - effective field goal percentage of the player
FT (Free Throws): integer - number of free throws made by the player
FTA (Free Throw Attempts): integer - number of free throw attempts by the player
FT% (Free Throw Percentage): float - percentage of free throws made by the player
ORB (Offensive Rebounds): integer - number of offensive rebounds by the player
DRB (Defensive Rebounds): integer - number of defensive rebounds by the player
TRB (Total Rebounds): integer - total rebounds by the player
AST (Assists): integer - number of assists made by the player
STL (Steals): integer - number of steals made by the player
BLK (Blocks): integer - number of blocks made by the player
TOV (Turnovers): integer - number of turnovers made by the player
PF (Personal Fouls): integer - number of personal fouls made by the player
PTS (Points): integer - total points scored by the player
```

Comment: It looks like age variable is not numeric, try `as.integer(age)` or `as.numeric(age)` to convert it to a number. Also to reference a column `[,"ColumnName"]` note the comma which tells R to read all rows matching the column.

Comment: Simba, we have no data so have no idea what should be working. Errors here seem clear to me: "undefined columns" means you don't have columns you think you have; "non-numeric" means it's not a number. Have you looked at your data, perhaps with `str(dataset)`, to see what type (numeric, character, logical) and correct spelling each column has?

Comment: Further, I don't know how the recommendation might have been suggested to you, but the [tag:machine-learning] tag is inappropriate for this question. Please don't spam tags.

Comment: @r2evans I downloaded the dataset, and added the dput of the the head to the question :-)

Comment: Simba hi! Welcome! A few thoughts so far: 1. `PTS` isn't qualitative data (it's the quantity of points, it's quantitative. 2. the name of the column is `'Pos'`, not `'POS'` 3. I can't reproduce the age or GS errors, have you included all of your code?

Comment: AH WAIT i think I know why you got the age and gs errors

Comment: why did you make it `header=FALSE`?

Comment: I just updated the question to have the new janky input. Apologies @r2evans

Comment: @Mark, you found the core issue (remove `header=FALSE`). I suggest you post as an answer.

Comment: too late @r2evans, add to yours

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR (after the fact): `header=FALSE` is wrong, you're spoiling your data and causing it to have no column names. Remove it.

```r
dataset <- read.csv("~/Downloads/nba_data_processed.csv")
```

and try it all again.

---

1. R (like almost all programming languages) is case-sensitive, so `"POS"` will not work, it's `"Pos"`.

   ```r
   for (PTS in cat_vars) {
     cat_freq <- table(dataset[PTS])
     print(paste("Frequency table for", PTS))
     print(cat_freq)
   }
   # [1] "Frequency table for Pos"
   # Pos
   #  C PF SG 
   #  3  1  2 
   # [1] "Frequency table for PTS"
   # PTS
   #  6.2  7.9  8.6    9  9.2 20.4 
   #    1    1    1    1    1    1
   ```

   Doing a `table` on continuous data is very unlikely to be fruitful, not sure what you intend to do with that.
2. Your `log(dataset$Age)` error does not happen with this `dataset`.

   ```r
   log(dataset$Age)
   # [1] 3.135494 3.367296 3.218876 3.091042 3.091042 3.178054
   dataset$LogAge <- log(dataset$Age)
   ```
3. Your `as.integer` error does not happen with this `dataset`. However, it's already `numeric`, so converting to integer may not be very meaningful depending on how you intend to use it.

   ```r
   class(dataset$GS)
   # [1] "numeric"
   dataset$GS <- as.integer(dataset$GS)
   ```
4. `hist(dataset$Tm, ...)` needs numeric data, but `Tm` is character, you can't do a histogram on it. You *can* do a `barplot` on the `table` of it, however, though I don't know if that's what you intended.

   ```r
   barplot(table(dataset$Tm), main="Tm Distribution", xlab="Tm")
   ```

   [image: basic barplot of Tm variable in dataset]
5. `plot(dataset$Tm, ...` isn't going to work well with characters (again), though you can sequence along them and change the x labels.

   ```r
   plot(seq_along(dataset$Tm), dataset$Age, main="Scatterplot: Tm vs. Age", 
        xlab="Tm", ylab="Age", xaxt="n", pch=16)
   axis(1, at = seq_along(dataset$Tm), labels = dataset$Tm)
   ```

   [image: base plot of Tm versus Age from dataset]

   As an intro, `ggplot2` deals a little more intuitively with categorical data.

   ```r
   library(ggplot2)
   ggplot(dataset, aes(Tm, Age)) +
     geom_point() +
     labs(title = "Scatterplot: Tm vs. Age")
   ```

   [image: ggplot of the same scatterplot, Tm versus Age]

Comment: Pts isn't qualitative data r2evans, why did you do a table of it???

Comment: Maybe you could change it to be a frequency table of the other *actual* categorical columns - the  team column! :-)

Comment: it seems very premature to give an answer to this question when we're still in the dark about why OP got errors. Also, this is a uni assignment, I thought we weren't meant to spoonfeed?

Comment: @Mark, I understand (and share) your concern that `Pts` should not be `table`d. The point of this answer was to step through the OP's complaints and to show where there are or are not problems. It's a little speculative, I agree. But I'm ***NOT*** going to do all of their analysis for them, especially when it seems rather clear that this is for a class of some sort that wants to walk them through some basic steps. Perhaps the lessons was to clearly demonstrate that `table` of continuous data is not very helpful. _This_ is not spoon-feeding, this is explaining/dispelling errors.

Comment: @Mark Often we need to show that the "reproducible" question does not reproduce the errors presented, or that it produces other errors _not_ presented. This can be frustrating but can be a learning moment for the OP; often it causes more conversation where we learn some other step(s) they did that they thought had no impact on the data.

Comment: I get what you mean- a lot of what you wrote is pointing out the things which don't add up, and walking them through basic steps for things, which is great! I guess maybe I misunderstood the nature of answers. I was under the impression it was something like, by analogy, the question asker is like a person in a tv show who asks "who killed my wife?", and the answerer is like Poirot, identifying the murderer and explaining everything and creating some sense of justice. But your question is more akin to Poirot telling the husband his story has lots of holes and pointing to

Comment: some things he could investigate, which left me a little cold  apologies for the bad analogy